# Intent is always null when taking a picture

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera, onactivityresult

I am new to Kotlin and Android Studio and am running into an issue retreiving a picture from the camera.

Intent is always null in the onActivityResult so no image will be displayed. When I remove data!==null, I get the following error

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity

Here is my code:

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.startButton.setOnClickListener{
            dispatchTakePictureIntent()
        }
    }

    val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1

    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.d("ERROR", "An error occured")
                    null
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            this,
                            "pim.android.photoapp.fileprovider",
                            it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
//        Log.d("DATA", data.toString())

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !== null) {
            val imageBitmap = data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
        }
    }

    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
                "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pim.android.photoapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PhotoApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="pim.android.photoapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

@xml/file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here? Any answers would be appreciated

Comment: `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return an `Intent`. Your photo should be in the location specified in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you mean I have to change the EXTRA_OUTPUT in putExtra to ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE? Because that works kind of, only the picture will not be sharp

Comment: "Do you mean I have to change the EXTRA_OUTPUT in putExtra to ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE?" -- you already have that. You are not using it in `onActivityResult()`, though. I was not clear in my earlier comment: when you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, do not assume that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will return an `Intent`, and *never* look for a `data` extra in the `Intent`. That is what you are doing now. Instead, in `onActivityResult()`, use the photo that should be written to where you requested in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image data will not be returned by the intent on the onActivityResult, but rather it will be saved on the file path created (If file creation was successful considering the permission aspect in different android versions)

Step 1. make the photofile a global variable

```
    private var photoFile: File? = null
```

Step 2. Update your dispath method with the glabal photofile

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
             photoFile: File? = try {
                createImageFile()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.d("ERROR", "An error occured")
                null
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            photoFile?.also {
                val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        "pim.android.photoapp.fileprovider",
                        it
                )
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3. Update your on activity result

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
//        Log.d("DATA", data.toString())

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
photoFile?.let {
                val imageBitmap: Bitmap=  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(it.absolutePath)
binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```